# Guardar Fecha y hora desde Excel a Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Buenas estoy tratando de guardar los datos de Excel a mysql en PHP pero en la columna del archivo Excel tiene tipo de datos que es la fecha y hora, cuando hago el proceso en el PHP me guarda los datos tipo int, no estoy seguro si debo implementar la función DATETIME() en el código este es el código php.

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('estacion.xlsx');

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
 {
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
    {
        $html.= "<tr>";
        $FECHA_HORA = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj_conexion, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
        $HUMEDAD_RELATIVA_DEL_AIRE = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj_conexion, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datos (fecha_hora, max) VALUES ('" . $FECHA_HORA . "','" . $HUMEDAD_RELATIVA_DEL_AIRE . "')";
        mysqli_query($obj_conexion, $sql);
        $html. = '<td>' . $FECHA_HORA . '</td>';
        $html. = '<td>' . $HUMEDAD_RELATIVA_DEL_AIRE . '</td>';
        $html. = "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes usar el código [explicado aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19675291/5587982) para obtener la fecha mediante métodos propios de la biblioteca `PHPExcel`, por cierto, esta biblioteca ya no es mantenida y se recomienda usar ahora [`PHPSpreadSheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Comment: No sé si lo has visto, pero si le das formato general a una columna con fecha - hora, encontrarás un número entero. Revisa la documentación que te sugieren

Comment: Muchas gracias he revisado la documentación y me resulto útil, gracias de nuevo!